Main 400 Amp service to Distribution Panel (400 Amp) which connects to 4 Subpanels (225 Amps each)
I am trying to fix the mistakes that a contractor made while installing and running the main connection as well as sub panels within our family home that was being rebuilt.
I need some input in regard to methods in which a 400 AMP single phase double pole connection can be distributed to the other panels within the house.
Currently, there is an aluminum over-head wire which connects from the pole to a separate meter box which houses the meter outside, it has a ground rod as well as copper ground wire connected to it. From there it is connected via a steel conduit using 3 large copper individual wires (of unknown AWG) next to it to a separate main breaker box housing a single 250 Amp Siemens QR22B250 double Pole Breaker. The Ground connection from the Meter box is bonded to the Neutral in this box.
There is a hole behind that second main shutoff box that runs 3 wires to a 40 Space Siemens S4040L1200 Panel Within the Garage. That Panel does not have a shutoff and has bonded Neutral and Ground Connections. It is the connection point for the remainder panels on the First, Second, as well as Basement Floors. This Siemens Garage Panel is not Plug on Neutral, The Other Homeline panels are.
The main feed wires coming from that Garage Panel to the Sub-panels are Aluminum SER with 3 Conductors being 1 AWG and one bare Ground being 3 AWG.
I am sure that connecting 3 panels to one panel that is rated for 200 Amps is not right, I limited the current to 100 amps per panel at that Garage Panel and disconnected the basement panel as it was not connected to anything being that it was not completed. All of the Subpanels are too small for the number of circuits going to them (30 spaces/circuits)
My questions are as follows, I have come to the understanding that I need to change that one Main Shutoff breaker box outside to a distribution box that can accept a 400 Amp Breaker from the meter and have 4x 225 Amp Breaker shutoffs going to the remaining panels which will be changed out for 60 Spaces/120 Circuits each. I need to know if such an outdoor rated main distribution panel exists and if this is the proper way to approach this. I am aware that the wire coming from the meter must be 600 Kcmil copper to support such a load.
Also, it has come to my attention that all the feed wires running to all the sub-panels is undersized for the load that they should be able to handle, SER 3C 1AWG/1C 3AWG from my understanding is rated for 100-110 Amps in a Dwelling Environment, I confirmed this from the manufacturer Priority Wire.
My correction would be to replace all of the SER wire to 300 kcmil-300 kcmil-300kcmil-4/0 AWG Wire, have each panel have its own Ground Rod at least 6 ft. apart outside, Neutrals and Grounds Separated, remove any and all bonding in the Garage Panel and only have the supposed distribution panel outside bonded to the neutral.
What would be the proper way to approach correcting this situation? My largest concern is the connection of all the sub-panels outside correctly and safely.
Edit:
Additional Information: The Plan in and of itself doesn't specify any particular panels or breakers, it just states that x panel is of x number of circuits, and each circuit is x number of amps utilizing x type wire, and their locations.
Added Photos of the Outside Meter Box and Main Breaker Box as well as inside the Main Breaker Box.
Any Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :)




What did your plans call for,  and were they followed?  Was this inspected?

The Plan did call for a 400 Amp Main Connection and a couple of sub-panels, this was not followed by the contractors which initially did the work. The Town did inspect the work but now I understand that for the rough they only inspect for code violations, and not if they were following the plan.

If contractor did not follow the plan/contract, then you do not fix.  You get the contractor to fix or get another contractor and bill the first(which gets into legal matters).  Talk to contractor and see why the plan was not followed first, there might be a reason.

Unfortunately that ship has sailed, I am left fixing the mess left by them and minimizing the losses. I can't go back and rip everything out as there are many home runs for the various circuits such as outlets and switches in the house to each panel. Which is why I ask for the outside Distribution Panel specifically.

Are you sure your meter can and meter are rated for a 400 amp service?

I called the Local Utility Service Provider to get clarification as to what is installed here. That I am hoping can be addressed later on as it is separate to the Main Breaker. My path is to first correct the house interconnections and then the supply. Seeing as the Meter box is a separate entity it can hopefully be kept that way and inter connected to this Distribution Panel for which I asked this question.

Can you post photos of the meter can/meter please?

Certainly :)
I have just edited the post and inserted two photos, one is the Meter Box & Main Breaker Box, and the other is the Meter Face itself. Thank You.

Added one more photo showing the internal contents of the Main Breaker Box.

Have you done an actual load calculation for each panel?  What you want to do seems like over kill: 34 circuits for the garage and 30 circuits  for each floor. Plus you can use tandum breakers.  Have you had any problems with the system as currently wired?  You have a 320 meter and a 250 amp main breaker. That's a lot of power for a residence.

Yes, there was a load Calc Done initially. For not complicating the post even more I left out insignificant details. To answer your questions and points in detail, there are 3 Panels as described in my initial post. The 2 panels inside the house are 30 spaces/Circuits. I was going to move one into the garage as the Siemens Panel is not Plug on Neutral compliant. On that same note, Tandem Breakers would be nice but they don't exist to my knowledge for Arc Fault Code Compliance as is required by more Recent NEC Code.

Thank you for that information, the house is not completed currently, I am absolutely sure I will run into problems, the ovens are double pole and there are 2, there are provisions for 50 amp double pole Induction Cooktops, Electric Clothes Driers, as well as Split Systems just to name a few things. Furthermore I believe the Bathrooms have some type of Jet Tubs which I don't have the Specs for at the moment. Load Calcs were done anticipating roughly the types of appliances as well as high current draw equipment would be in the house.

Based upon the Original Approved Plans, the issue is with items such as the the Tubs for example needing separate Circuits, and therefore Breakers, I think they have heaters in them thus requiring double pole breakers and thus two spots on the Panel, the original plan had an 84 circuit panel as well as I believe 2 40 circuit panels, but they obviously were not totally full to facilitate future changes but were about 75% full. Things have changed inside from the initial approvals for various reasons, but circuits have increased as opposed to decreasing.

Is the utility giving you honest 400A service? Because the 250A breaker there just makes no sense. What a difficult and expensive way to do that thing.   Speaking of expensive, all breakers over 200A are not affordable, so that is not how 400A service is done.  (and I wonder if your guys did not know that).   400A service is done as two 200A panels.
If it were me, I would plan to install two of these on the outside of the house. These are 200A Siemens "ranch panel / trailer panel" which have a main breaker, 8 breaker spaces, and "thru lugs" to take the full 200A onward to another panel.  I would "plan to" install one immediately to the right of the meter pan right where the 250A is now.  And another one just to the right of that.   It's also common to put them on both sides of the meter pan, but I have a feeling wires will reach better if they are both on the right.
I would use RMC conduit with two LBs to drop out the bottom of the meter pan, then across the space allocated for the left panel, to the final location of the right panel. I would bend that mid-stretch so it pops up a bit, giving a way to get conduits into the bottom of the future left panel.
Now you have two 200A main breakers and 16 breaker spaces, along with two pairs of thru lugs.
I would populate the thru lugs and breaker spaces with runs to the various subpanels.
However, I would take care to try to have all the critical loads powered off one of the two 200A panels, preferably the right one. That will make life easier should you ever want a generator interlock or battery/V2X system.
